# PHP post data isn't being sent through

Tags: php, html, web, contact-form

I have tried everything I can think to try, but this is still not working.

I've used different forms and PHP mail scripts but nothing seems to work. The email is being sent but the info is always blank. **See screenshot for example**.

[image: This is the screenshot link]

Here is the form code:

```
    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span7">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                

            </form>
```

and here is the **entire PHP file** (`sendemail.php`):

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );


    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['first_name']));
    $lastname = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['last_name']));  
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = "Website Contact Form";
    $email_to = '//removed real email address';


$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;

 
    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$email_from>");

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');


    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

The web page of the form with the current code [you see here running here](http://minha-consulting.com/contactus.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line of $Body should start without "."

```
$Body = "Name: ";
```

If you defined variable with lowercase you cant call it with upper.

```
$test != $Test
```

Just copy this and replace whit your code:

```
    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['first_name']));
    $lastname = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['last_name']));  
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

$subject = 'Email Subject';
$headMail = "From: your@email.address\r\n";
$headMail .= "From: your@email.address\r\n";
$bodyMail = "Name: ";
$bodyMail .= $name . ' ' . $lastname;
$bodyMail .= "\n";
$bodyMail .= "Email: ";
$bodyMail .= $email;
$bodyMail  .= "\n";
$bodyMail .= "Message: ";
$bodyMail .= $message;

mail($email, $subject, $bodyMail, $headMail);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable names two times (uppercase and lowercase) and you are sending your email twice. This is a bit messy. Here are some issues in your code:

- `$Body` is not defined
- `$Email` is not defined (uppercase)
- `$Message` is not defined (uppercase)
- Why are you using stripslashes? Better use [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).
- clean up your code with proper indentions and use a PHP coding standard

This way bugs will be much easier to find.

Comment: Your suggestions did not work at all.

`<?php
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $status = array(
  'type'=>'success',
  'message'=>'Email sent!'
 );

    $name = ($_POST['first_name']);
    $lastname = ($_POST['last_name']);  
    $email = ($_POST['email']); 
    $message = ($_POST['message']);

    $email_from = "Website Contact Form";
    $email_to = 'geefuller5@gmail.com';
    $body = "Name: ".$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\nMessage: ".$message;
    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
    echo json_encode($status);
    die;`

Comment: That is my new PHP code and it is still not sending the data through.

@kuchar

Comment: Please update your question with the modified code - in the comments its just not readable...

Answer (score 0):

> The variable name is case-sensitive.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

`$Message` and `$message` are not same. Similarly fix other variables.

Answer (score 0):

use $message instead of $Message as you defined lowercase 'm' above.

```
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
```